# Cocoa: Load Different View Controllers depending on input from App Delegate

Tags: swift, macos, appdelegate

I am trying to trigger 1 of 2 different flows via the AppDelegate but seem to be struggling.

see below as the image:

[image: Storyboard with 2 views]
How do I instantiate each these two different view controllers if only one can be tied into the main NSWindow Controller?

I managed to get them being triggered using "addChildWindow" using the following code- but then I am unable to segue to any subsequent view controllers.

Here is the code I am using to instantiate the view controllers:

```
   if let pboardString = pboard.stringForType(NSStringPboardType){
            print(pboardString)
           let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let destcontroller  =  storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("pickProject") as! WizardTextFromPasteboardVC
            destcontroller.weburlFromPaste = pboardString

            let numWindows = NSApplication.sharedApplication().windows
            if let window = NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow {
                if numWindows.count >= 1{
                    let childWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: destcontroller)
                    window.addChildWindow(childWindow, ordered: .Above)
                }
                else if numWindows.count == 0 {
                    window.contentViewController = destcontroller
                }
```

Comment: Why don't you create two buttons on the main window, each of which is connected to a respective view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to keep the default segue that provides window content.  If you delete it and provide two view controllers that can be instantiated by id, then your application delegate can decide when launch finishes.

Such as:

```
let selection: Int = 2

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var controller: NSViewController
    if selection == 1 {
        controller = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("view_controller") as! NSViewController
    } else {
        controller = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("view_controller_2") as! NSViewController
    }
    let window = NSApp.windows[0]
    window.contentViewController = controller
}
```

Comment: Phillip Mills - thanks for this- but if I did it this way - how would I subsequently call controllers from those controllers... using segues?

Comment: The same as you would in any other circumstances, as far as I can tell.  I just hooked up a segue in the storyboard from a button on my second controller to display a third controller as a sheet and it worked fine.